# Does the integers modulo $n$ with the addition modulo $n$ form a commutative group of size $n$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

According to the book I'm reading (Advanced Linear Algebra by Nicholas Loehr, p4-see photo), the integers modulo $n$ with the addition modulo $n$ form a commutative group of size $n$.

But I cannot see how each element has an inverse that satisfies the axiom 4 here. (for every a in the group, there exists $-a$ that leads to $a+(-a)=0$).

I think it would make sense if the integers modulo is symmatric
(ex, it is $\{-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, with $n$ being $5$).

But the specific example in the book is: $\{0, 1, 2, 3, ..n-1\}$ as you can see.

Is this an error in the book or am I missing something?

[image: the page in question describing this]

Comment: $1\oplus(n-1)=0$, $2\oplus(n-2)=0$, etc.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. How did I completely miss that..! Thanks for the speedy answer.

Answer (score 1):

*As @LordSharktheUnknown describes in the comments . . .*

No, it's not an error.

The inverses of the operation $\oplus$ can be delineated with a few examples, like so:

$$\begin{align}
 1\oplus (n-1)&=1+(n-1)-n \\
&=0, \\
2\oplus (n-2)&=2+(n-2)-n\\
&=0, \\
&\vdots
\end{align}$$